# Finding example domain that uses AAACertificateServices cert

Tags: ssl-certificate

How can I find a domain whose root certificate is [AAACertificateServices](https://support.sectigo.com/Com_KnowledgeDetailPage?Id=kA03l00000117cL)? Note this is a Comodo certificate.

To prepare for a [dependent server whose certificate will change soon](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=7gx0a2lp), it looks my servers do have this certificate. However, I'd like to verify that ssl requests will work now by sending a request to a domain that is already using AAACertificateServices.